# Текстовый редактор с hashcode.ru

Tags: редактор-текста, markdown, javascript

Здравствуйте!Если это позволительно, подскажите, где взять такой же текстовый редактор, как на этом сайте в комментариях и при добавлении поста? уж больно нравится!

Comment: `<textarea></textarea>`?

Comment: это html-блок ввода многострочного текста. мне нужны исходники функциональной части. 
ЗЫ Поправочка: не в комментариях, а при добавлении ответа.

Comment: Так посмотрите исходный код страницы и увидите, что там используется для Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите точно такой же - ковыряйтесь в исходниках [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) - движка, на котором Хэшкод написан. Если не хотите ковыряться - пользуйтесь [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) или чем-нибудь подобным.